# Unable to ssh into a linux machine

Tags: linux, ssh, putty, iptables

I have a Linux machine running Centos 7.
I am trying to ssh into the machine using putty or WinScp and unable to do that.

I have opened the ssh port using:
`sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT`

I have paled the public key inside the authorized_key file.
I have edited the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file and enabled the `PublickeyAuthentication`.

After that i have restarted the sshd service: `systemctl restart sshd.service`.

Still, i am not able to reach the servers. I thought it might be an internet connection issues but I am able to go online from the machine.
The error i receive from putty upon connection is : `Network error: Connection timed out`.

What am i missing? how do i fix that issue?
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to properly troubleshoot the issue - step by step.

1. is port opened (netstat)
2. are packets reaching host (tcpdump)
3. how machine replies; where the reply packets go (tcpdump)
4. check all firewall rules; it is possible that other rule matches (iptables)
5. check routing; you may even have multiple routing tables (ip route)

It would be easier to troubleshoot firewall if you could switch it off temporarily but that is not always an option.

Comment: Please ask additional questions and I will keep updating answer as we go.

Comment: After using `netstat` i saw that the ports hasn't been actually open, I haven't saved the iptables configuration. I ended up changing the ssh port in the `sshd_config` file end opening the port  / saving it in the iptables.

Answer (score 2):

I believe `--dport` is part of the tcp module and requires the `-m tcp` option to use it. Full command to accept incoming tcp port 22 would then be:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: I have added this rule. It did not change the outcome, still cant connect.

Answer (score 2):

```
iptables -A INPUT -i venet0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "ALLOW ESTABLISHED connections"
iptables -A INPUT -i venet0 -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "ALLOW new SSH connections"
```

replace `venet0` with your networkinterface, like `eth0`

if it doesn't work, what is the output of `netstat -tulpen | grep ':22'` or `lsof -4` and `iptables -L -v -n`

`-m tcp` is not requierd for `--dport`